# Ошибка при парсинге 2-х одинаковых тегов подряд в Simple html dom parser

Tags: php, html, json, парсер

Искал на stackoverflow и ответа на свой вопрос не нашел :(

Ребят, возникла такая проблема - есть код:

```
<div class="user-item"> <div class="user-item__pic"> <a href="/1542860296246269.jpg" alt="Александр Сергеевич"></a>
 </div>     
<div class="user-item__info">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
                                <h4 class="user-item__title">
                                    <a href="https://site.ru">
                                        Виктоия АА </a>
                               </h4>
                                <div class="user-item__params">
                                    <div class="user-item__params-row">
                                                                                <div class="user-item__param-name">
                                                Специализация:
                                            </div>
                                            <strong class="user-item__param-value">
                                                Продажа квартир                                        </strong>
                                                                        </div>
                                    <div class="user-item__params-row">
                                        <div class="user-item__param-name">
                                            Риелтор                                    </div>
                                        <div class="user-item__param-value">Киев</div>
                                    </div>
                                                                                                                                        <div class="user-item__params-row">
                                            <div class="user-item__param-name">Телефоны</div>
                                            <div class="user-item__param-value">
                                                <span class="nowrap">
                                                +38 (111) 1234567 </span>, <span class="nowrap"> +38 (222) 1234567      </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                                                </div>
                                <div>
```

Проблема в том, что не дается спарсить номера телефонов, если их больше 1-го. Выводит ошибку: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on array.

Сам процесс парсинга именно тега "nowrap" (номера телефонов) выглядит так:

```
foreach($html->find('*')->find('.nowrap') as $a)  {            // название товара
    array_push($array_phone,$a->plaintext);   }
```

Именно на эти строки и ругается. 
**Пожалуйста**, подскажите, как решить эту проблему и объединить номера в одну строку (как вариант, через запятую).

Answer (score 1):

Выкиньте `find('*')`. Этот поиск возвращает массив элементов, и следующий find даёт ошибку.

```
foreach( $html->find('.user-item') as $item ) {
    foreach ( $item->find('.nowrap' as $a ) {
        array_push( $array_phone, $a->plaintext );
    }
}
```

Comment: Так тоже пробовал, в таком случае он берет телефон с первого     <span class="nowrap">. Следующий же  "nowrap" в этом же divе от дает другой (следующей записи). А нужно, если у человека записано 2 номера - они оба и уходили в массив.

Comment: Пользователи каждый в `user-item__info`?

Comment: Уважаемый **KAGG Design!** Спасибо за помощь.
Родительский div - "user-item". 

                            <div class="user-item">
                <div class="user-item__pic">
                    <a href="/1542860296246269.jpg" alt="Александр Сергеевич"></a>                </div>
                <div class="user-item__info">

Comment: Странно, должно было работать и так. Поправил ответ.

Comment: **KAGG Design**, все равно выводит только 1 номер телефона. При этом если у первого юзера было 2 номера, то 2-й номер уже присваивается следующему юзеру, а его - следующему... и так далее. Получаю вот отсюда - rieltor.ua/users

Comment: Какой вывод? Здесь  только сбор. Кроме того, в массиве нет никакого сопоставления юзеров и телефонов. У вас в $array_phone одни телефоны.

Comment: "Здесь только сбор". Вы имеете ввиду ручной?

Comment: Где в вашем коде какой-то вывод на экран? Echo, var_dump, print_r? Где сопоставление юзеров и телефонов? Вы вообще о чем говорите? У вас вывод организован неправильно, а со сбором телефонов в массив все в порядке.